# Individual column searching (text inputs) datatable angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, datatables

how can I use this option [Individual column searching](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)  for datatable  in angular 5

How can I solve this please ?

- this is my TS file

  dtOptions: DaaTables.Settings = {};

  ```
  ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.items)
      this.dtOptions = {
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        pageLength: 5,
        ordering:true,
        orderCellsTop:true,
      };
      this.service.getUsers().subscribe(users=>{
        this.users=users;
        this.dtTrigger.next();
        console.log(this.users)

      });

    }
  ```

### this is my HTML file

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="ID" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="name" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="username" /></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>username</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I followed on your link and got DataTable is not available for Angular. You can use Kendo Angular UI, Ag-grid or any other who provides Angular module for datatable

Comment: Example here: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/individual-column-filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do :

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('ContactsComponent - ngAfterViewInit()');
        this.dtTrigger.next();
        this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
            dtInstance.columns().every(function () {
                const that = this;
                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    console.log('search(): ' + that.search());
                    console.log('value: ' + this['value']);
                    if (that.search() !== this['value']) {
                        that.search(this['value'])
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
  });
```

In HTML file, add footer with name = search-yourfield :

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
       <th>Sélection</th>
       <th><input type="text" placeholder="Search ID" name="search-idaicontact"/></th>
       <th><input type="text" placeholder="Search first name" name="search-identifiant"/></th>
       <th><input type="text" placeholder="Search last name" name="search-nom"/></th>
       <th><input type="text" placeholder="Search last name" name="search-prenom"/></th>
       <th>Action</th>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
```